# how to use object with reactive-form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I use in my reactive-form a date-range-picker. So my used variable is an object.

{start: timestamp, end: timestamp, timezone: string, max: timestamp,
min: timestamp}

When i display it in my input, I get : [Object - Object]

I would like to display something like this : 
{{ date.start + '-' + date.end }}

```
this.testDate = { start: 1565690444, end: 1565890444, min: 1265690441, max: 1640704921, timezone : "Asia/Dubai"};
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
this.configureForm = this.fb.group(<any>{
  test: [
    this.testDate,
    [
      Validators.required,
      UtilsValidator.periodFormat(DateFormatType.Default, this.testDate.timezone),
      UtilsValidator.dateMin(this.testDate.min, DateFormatType.Default, this.testDate.timezone),
      UtilsValidator.dateMax(this.testDate.max, DateFormatType.Default, this.testDate.timezone)
    ]
  ]});
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="configureForm">
<ex-form-field>
      <input[formControlName]="'test'">
      <i [exDateTimePicker]  [exDateTimeFormControl]="getField('test')"> * </i>
    </ex-form-field>
</form>
```

Could you help me plz ?

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproduction of your issue on stackblitz please?

Comment: well an Input can Display, one value. You want to show multiple, did i understand you correct ? Also do you want to edit the values in the Input ? Otherwise you could just use a <p> and use interpolation {{ }} like you wanted to

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-perfqk :D

Yeah. i want to keep my object cause i need it in my range picker but i want a different display.

Answer (score 0):

a form control exists if we has an input or not. The idea is that your control change the formControl, and display his value, but you can not write a simple `<input formControlName="test">`

A simple example if has a input with NgModel

```
<input [ngModel]="configureForm.get('test').value.start+ '-'+ configureForm.get('test').value.end"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
       (ngModelChange)="change($event)"
  >
```

Where you function change can be like

```
change(value)
  {
    const values=value.split('-');
    if (values.length==2)
    {
      const control=this.configureForm.get('test');
      this.configureForm.get('test').setValue(
         {...control.value,start:+values[0],end:+values[1]},
         {emit:false})
    }
  }
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsx94j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Dude, it seems to be perfect. i will try right now. Thk a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Hum.. It not working unfortunately . my validator doesn't be updated and when i edit my input by typing inside my display is not updated too !

i tried this exemple (with a simply (Validators.required)):

```
  <input
      [(ngModel)] = "dateTest"
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
      (change)="updateDate($event)" />
```

TypeScript :

```
    get dateTest() {
     if (!this.configureForm.get('test').value.start)
        return null;

   return this.configureForm.get('test').value.start + '-' + 
   this.configureForm.get('test').value.end;}



    updateDate(value: Event) {
     this.configureForm.controls['dateTest'].setValue({start: null, 
     end: null});}
```

Comment: maybe it's simpler like that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-perfqk